# Show another button next to Delete on UITableViewCell with a swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app is build in a way that a user enters data inside a `UITableView` in `UIViewcontroller` A (one line of data or more) and can save it to disk. In the next `UIViewController` B he can see all the saved data.

I'm using this:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    }    
}
```

To show a delete button on a cell with a swipe. How can I show an edit button on a single cell (that will appear the same way the delete button appears) next to delete button?
(the edit button will take the data back to the first `UIViewController` A for editing but that's not really relevant)

I thought about using a swipe gesture but got an error saying I can't use that on a prototype cell. I tried using it on the all `UITableVIew` but that conflicts with the swipe delete gesture.

Comment: Add a swipegesture on the cell and add functionality to show other button..

Comment: use costome cell for doing this task

Comment: Hi Segev, how did you finally done this ?

Comment: @Wongzigii Hey, as far as I can recall I used custom buttons. For delete and for other things. I don't think you can add other stuff to that built in gesture.

Comment: Check this awesome repo: [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)

Comment: Cool repo, although keep in mind that the answer above was asked in before..hmm.. I think even before iOS 6. Much better API to use now without a lot of customisation for that kind of thing.